# AngularJs: Not able to clear input field after form sumbit

Tags: angularjs

Below is my angularjs code: I am not able to clear inputComment field after form submit.

Here i am able to add record successfully but after adding record i am trying to clear the input field but i am not able to do it.

```
HTML code:
<body ng-app="taskDemo" ng-controller="taskController">
    <div class="widget-body">
        <form class="add-task" ng-if="addNewClicked" ng-init="addNewClicked=false;">
        <div class="">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input name="comment" ng-model="inputComment" type="text" class="form-control"   > 
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button ng-click="addTask(inputComment)" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New Task
                        </button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

JS Code:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
        app = angular.module('taskDemo', []);
        app.controller('taskController', function($scope, $http){
                $scope.addTask = function (task) {
                $http.post("ajax/addTask.php?task="+task)
                    .success(function ($response) {
                       getTaskList();                 
                    });
                 $scope.inputComment = '';  

            };
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What's inside `getTaskList()` function? Make sure you are not defining `$scope.inputComment` inside.

Comment: Here is getTaskList() Code: function getTaskList() {
        $http.post("ajax/getTaskList.php")
            .success(function ($response) {
                $scope.taskList = $response;
            });
    }

Comment: @Kasyx: Not defining $scope.inputComment inside getTaskList() but i am using $scope module in it.

Comment: I think you should declare $scope.inputComment = {}; outside of function also.

Comment: @Ved I tired that also its not working but initial object on page load...it means it will create other issue

Comment: No it will not create any issue..  And I will again ask you that, are you sure $scope.inputComment = {}; outside and inside the function is not clearing the input field.

Comment: I think something is missing, where is defined "addNewClicked"? Probably u are making another scope somewhere and your inputComment from one scope is not the same thing as inputComment from another. Make sure that u still use the same scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about Prototypical Inheritance here : [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Change yr controller to this :

```
     app.controller('taskController', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.inputComment ={value:''};  
            $scope.addTask = function (task) {
            $http.post("ajax/addTask.php?task="+task)
                .success(function ($response) {
                   getTaskList();                 
                });
             $scope.inputComment ={value:''};  

        };
    }
```

and Inside yr HTML page change this

```
<input name="comment" ng-model="inputComment" type="text" class="form-control"   >
```

to

```
<input name="comment" ng-model="inputComment.value" type="text" class="form-control"   >
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to note what's actually the problem and why your solution may work.